# How to create an instance of an imported class in another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

**User.js**

```
class User {

  constructor() {
    this.fisrtName
    this.lastName
  }

  get fullName() {
    `${this.firtName} ${this.lastName}`
  }

}

export default User
```

**Test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {User} from './User'

class Test extends React.Component {

  testClick(e) {
    const user = new User() //error! because User is undefined.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.testClick.bind(this)}>test</button>
    )
  }

}

export default Test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
import {User} from './User'
```

to

```
import User from './User'
```

Your mistake is that you are making **default export**: `export default User` inside of *User.js* module, but inside of *Test.js* you are making **named import**: `import {User} from './User'`.

Comment: !!!   worked! thanks!

Comment: Great to help you!